# Can't create Azure Event Grid Topic Subscription for Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-eventgrid

I have an event grid that is connected to a VNET.
I also have functions that are on the same VNET but with different subnets.

Azure is generating the following:

> Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Endpoint validation","message":"Destination endpoint not found. Resource details: resourceId: /subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites//functions/<function_name>. Resource should pre-exist before attempting this operation."}

An example of the function declaration in C#:

```cs
[FunctionName("MyFunction1")]
[return: EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "MyEventGridTopicUriSetting", TopicKeySetting = "MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")]
public async Task<CloudEvent[]> Run([EventGridTrigger]CloudEvent cloudEvent)
```

Weirdly, sometimes the subscription is generated but if you refresh the page later on, it disappears.

I'm fairly novice with Azure so this is largely new to me.

Any idea what I'm missing and could be causing this issue?